# MySql 5.1.x: insert into select .. encode strings

Tags: mysql, encoding, insert

i have 2 table with the same DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
If i copy some data from one table to the another with the command  'Insert into () Select ()', MySql encode the strings.
Example:

`2461/P/J- -- RESO N° RM10` became `2461/P/J- -- RESO N&#176; RM10`
note the conversion from `°` to `&#176;`

How can avoid this?
tnx in advice.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't happen when I try it (MySQL 5.1.41).  Are you doing this directly from the MySQL console, or are you perhaps doing it via the MySQL API - perhaps from PHP?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `src` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `dst` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

INSERT INTO src (data) VALUES ('2461/P/J- -- RESO N° RM10');

SELECT * FROM src;
+----+----------------------------+
| id | data                       |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | 2461/P/J- -- RESO N° RM10 |
+----+----------------------------+

INSERT INTO dst SELECT * FROM src;

SELECT * FROM dst;

+----+----------------------------+
| id | data                       |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | 2461/P/J- -- RESO N° RM10 |
+----+----------------------------+
```

Comment: great and complete example mike! i try me too this test and it pass..all green! But...then what happen in my table?.
Hmmm i retry your example using my tables and the error not happen!
The table is very old (come from a database that was start with mysql 4.0.x..)...i'm starting to suppose that the problem reside in the oldest row: maybe another encoding?

Comment: ok another strange thing happen: i retry to copy only 1 of the 'problematic' row...and this time no encoding happen! Only when i copy all the rows. Same client and context (sqlyog for windows)

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify the data in the original table? If you were having charset encoding issues, you would be seeing gargage characters and the like, not HTML entites. MySQL does not convert from/to HTML/XML entities as your example suggests.

Comment: in fact! all i can expect from mysql but not an 'html conversion' (for this i'm here :)